# JQuery animate lags on first run

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-animate, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

I'm troubleshooting a bug in a UI where the first time the menu is opened it is very slow.  Anywhere from 1-3 seconds.  Subsequent openings are just as fast as you would expect.

Below you will see the code, then after that a few javascript profiles.  You'll notice on each first run (after a page load) that `(program)` is at the top and is taking >500ms of the total time.   On subsequent runs (second, third) you will see `(idle)` at the top and `(program)` only taking 40-90 ms.

Even though I only provided 5 data points below, I've run this dozens of times and it is very consistent.

**Can anyone explain this or at least give me some tips on how to troubleshoot further?**

*edit: I should note, the performance profiles below are in Chrome Canary.  The actual code runs in Coherent UI in Unity and the delay is multiplied.*

---

### Code:

```
function openPane(callback) {
    console.profile('openPane');
    if (!$pane.is(':visible')) {
        $pane.css('display', 'block');
    }

    if (typeof $slideinc.length !== 'undefined') {
        for (i = 0; i < $slideinc.length; i++) {
            // This element has been configured to slide with the pane element
            if ($dir == "left") {
                $($slideinc[i]).animate({
                    left: convertPXtoVW((parseFloat($slideorigins[i].left) + parseFloat($pane.outerWidth(true)) +
                                         parseFloat($paneorigin.left)).toString())
                }, function() {
                });
            } else {
                $($slideinc[i]).animate({
                    right: convertPXtoVW((parseFloat($slideorigins[i].right) + parseFloat($pane.outerWidth(true)) +
                                        parseFloat($paneorigin.right)).toString())
                }, function() {
                });
            }
        }
    }

    // Depending on the configured direction animate left or right
    if ($dir == "left") {
        $pane.animate({ left: convertPXtoVW($paneorigin.left) }, function () {
            console.profileEnd();
        });
    } else {
        $pane.animate({ right: convertPXtoVW($paneorigin.right) }, function () {
            console.profileEnd();
        });
    }
    // Attribute added to determine when pane is opened
    $pane.attr('data-pane-open', true);
}
```

---

### Profiles (First Page Load)

First run:

[image]

Second run:

[image]

---

### Profiles (Second Page Load)

---

First Run:

[image]

Second Run:

[image]

Third Run:

[image]

Comment: You can try `chrome://tracing` to find out what the (program) is doing. Also, it may be a bug in newer Chrome: try in an older portable Chrome like v55 or even older.

Comment: Well, since Coherent uses Chrome 28, I don't think it's a version thing :)

Comment: Looking at `tracing` now but it's new and greek to me so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a couple thumbnails that didn't get resized properly.  They were 4k textures, around 40 megs each.  Once they were resized properly the performance problem disappeared.